# Different url rewriting according to locations

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, fastcgi, nginx-location

I really don't find any documentation I find clear about URL rewriting (I can't understand it, as I unexpectedly find the documentation really hard to read for a non-native).

I'm looking for a way to rewrite all routes that matches `/*\.(js|png|jpg|css|ttf|xml)$/` toward `path/media/` and try existance of file then return it if exists, else `404 not found`

then if it begins with `/ajax/` redirect all of it toward `path/ajax/index.php`
else redirect all of it toward `path/www/index.php`

I don't quite understand how I should do it, for now I created 3 locations /media/, /ajax/ and /www/ but I don't know if it is the right way to use rewrite and not return, or are the locations the correct way to do it.

I don't really understand what I've written in my `sites-enabled/file` regarding fastcgi. is this a interpretor path ?

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

If I get it right, it means "if it ends with .php, and it exists in hierarchy, then execute it".

And I don't know if I should put that kind of stuff for each location that has to deal with php (/www/ and /ajax/), especially since I'm going to do some routing for both. Moreover, I don't know if it should be done that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest PHP configurations use a common `root` directive which is inherited by the location blocks, and in your case would be:

```
root path;
```

This means that `/www/index.php` and `/ajax/index.php` are both processed by the `location ~ \.php$` block.

The default action can be defined by the `try_files` directive within a `location /` block:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /www/index.php;
}
```

If you need a different default action for URIs which begin with `/ajax`, add a more specific location:

```
location /ajax {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /ajax/index.php;
}
```

If you do not want your media URIs to begin with `/media` you can override the `root` for one specific location:

```
location ~* \.(js|png|jpg|css|ttf|xml)$ {
    root path/media;
}
```

The `fastcgi_split_path_info` and `fastcgi_index` directives are unnecessary in your specific case. The `include fastcgi_params;` statement should be placed before any `fastcgi_param` directive to avoid the latter being inadvertently overridden:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

See the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/) for details.